# Matching two words if yes value is 1 else 0 python or Linux

Tags: python

I have 2 different files. And I want to match letters to each other. If the letters match the value will be 1 and rest will be 0.

```
file1.txt
a
b
c
d
e

file2.txt
a b c d e
```

My expected output

```
file3.txt

  a b c d e 
a 1 0 0 0 0
b 0 1 0 0 0
c 0 0 1 0 0
d 0 0 0 1 0 
e 0 0 0 0 1
```

How can I generate such a matrix?

Comment: What does this have to do with `linux` or `sh`?

Comment: Where is the code you have written so far, and what *specific* problems are you having with it?

Comment: StackOverflow is here to help you with any problem you have with code you wrote, not to ask others to write code for you (though they sometimes will to answer your question). Please share what you've tried and point out any problems you have getting it to work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's the code:

```
with open( 'file1.txt' ) as fin :
    file1 = fin.read().split()

with open( 'file2.txt' ) as fin :
    file2 = fin.read().split()

print ' '.join( [' '] + file1 )
for ch in file2 :
    print ' '.join( [ch] + ['1' if ch == i else '0' for i in file1] )
```

Here's the result:

```
  a b c d e
a 1 0 0 0 0
b 0 1 0 0 0
c 0 0 1 0 0
d 0 0 0 1 0
e 0 0 0 0 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable help. its really a great help for me.

There was an error that is after print have to use ( )



print (' '.join( [' '] + file1 ))

print (' '.join( [ch] + ['1' if ch == i else '0' for i in file1] ))

Comment: @jonson if you use python3 you have to use `print( ... )`, not just `print`.